# The barryvdh/laravel-dompdf set orientation to landscape not dispaly unicode correctly

Tags: php, html, laravel, pdf, barryvdh

I have a project where I need to display Unicode characters. I've successfully displayed them in portrait paper orientation. However, when I switch to landscape orientation, the characters do not display correctly.

Here is my laravel project and packages :

- laravel: 10.0,
- php: 8.1.0,
- barryvdh/laravel-dompdf: 2.0.1,
- barryvdh/laravel-snappy": 1.0.2,

i want to display Unicode : **ក្រុមហ៊ុន** but it showing **`áž‚áŸ„áž›áž”áŸ†ážŽáž„`**

Here is a function that I use to generate PDFs :

```
public function LogReportRender($id)
{
    $batchSize = 14;
    $offset = 0;
    $all_requests = [];
    $request_data = [];
    $log_report = ReportLog::find($id);
    $title = $log_report->name;
   
    
    do {
        $requests = AppRequest::where('form_id', $log_report->parent_id)
                    ->where('is_active', true)
                    ->where('main_status_id', MainStatusId::Complete)
                    ->skip($offset)
                    ->take($batchSize)
                    ->orderBy('request_date','asc')
                    ->get()
                    ->toArray();
        $all_requests[] = $requests;
        $offset += $batchSize;
    } while (!empty($requests));
    if (empty(end($all_requests))) {
        array_pop($all_requests);
    }
    $flattenedItems = array_merge(...$all_requests);
    $allIds = array_column($flattenedItems, 'id');
    if(count($all_requests) > 0){
        $request_data = RequestData::whereIn('request_id',$allIds)
                        ->where('is_active',true)
                        ->get();
    }
    if(count($all_requests) < 0){
        return back()->withInput()->with('export_msg', 'Report can not preview, input not yet complete');
    }
    $form_name = strtolower(str_replace('-', '_', $log_report->code));
    $view_path = 'layout.report.form.'.$form_name.'_all';
    $param = [
        'all_requests' => $all_requests,
        'request_data' => $request_data,
        'report' => $log_report,
    ];
    $pdf = PDF::loadView($view_path,$param)
            ->setPaper('a4')
            ->setOrientation('landscape')
            ->setOption('margin-bottom', 0);
    return $pdf->stream($title);
}
```

Comment: Are the characters in the body or where are they? Can you show some code?

Comment: I take characters from a database table named 'customer,' which has a column of type VARCHAR. I've tried all PHP methods to convert anomalous text to UTF-8, but it doesn't seem to work.  Here is the code that i write it direct in blade file.

`Customer::find($customer_id)->name ?? null`

Comment: Maybe edit your question and show some code there. How are you creating the pdf instance and if its a blade file, maybe show some code of that, too. Generally speaking, there are several ways of telling the pdf to be utf8 so please show what you have so far.

Comment: also maybe have a look at this https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/585

Comment: And maybe look at other pdf libraries. mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf for instance

Comment: Thank you. I have just edited and am now showcasing all the functions that I created for the PDF.

Comment: Have you tried something like `$pdf->save($path.'/my_pdf_name.pdf', 'UTF-8'); return response()->download($path.'/my_pdf_name.pdf');`?

Comment: Thanks, but previewing before downloading is a requirement.

Comment: Well okay, then try to preview it. The point is in my linked thread there seems to be working solutions when you return a reponse() function instead of a pdf function, something like `return response()->file($pathToPdf)`